# How to concatenate two datasets if not all the variables are the same?

Tags: matlab

I have two datasets that have different number of columns:

ds1:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
```

ds2:

```
A   C   D
2   3   4
```

Now I want to merge these two datasets:

result:

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   0
2   3   0   4
```

As you can see, I just want to add 0, NaN or a blank if the variable names are not present in both datasets. I tried to use `cat` and `join`, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any hints?

Comment: Can you show how you declare these datasets? Are they cell arrays?

Comment: @Floris I load them from a file

Answer (score 3):

Here is an ugly way to do it - and then a cleaner way below (added later). Problem is that as soon as you are working with cell arrays (since the data type is mixed - letters for the columns, then numbers) life gets hard. You can probably do better by creating a structure where column names and data are two separate arrays (see below)... but for now here is "a solution". I made life a little bit more interesting by having different numbers of rows in the two datasets as well as different numbers of columns - just to make sure that didn't break something.

```
ds1 = {'a','bb','c';1,2,3};
ds2 = {'aa','c','d', 'e';2,3,4,5; 5,6,7,8};
cols = unique({ds1{1,:} ds2{1,:}});

ds3 = cols;
n1 = size(ds1,1) - 1;
%%
for ii = 1:size(ds1,2)
    ci = find(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, ds1{1,ii}), cols));
    if numel(ci) > 0
        for jj = 1:n1
            ds3{1+jj,ci} = ds1{1+jj, ii};
        end
    end
end
n2 = size(ds2, 1) - 1;
for ii = 1:size(ds2,2)
    ci = find(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, ds2{1,ii}), cols));
    if numel(ci) > 0
        for jj = 1:n2
            ds3{1+n1+jj,ci} = ds2{1+jj, ii};
        end
    end
end
```

The resulting merged array:

```
'a'   'aa'  'bb'   'c'    'd'   'e'
[1]     []   [ 2]   [3]    []    []
 []   [ 2]     []   [3]   [4]   [5]
 []   [ 5]     []   [6]   [7]   [8]
```

Not optimal, I'm sure - but it does what you asked... I hate doing this in loops but couldn't see a way around it. I hope one of the "real Matlab experts" will puke when he sees this and be spurred into giving you the clever one line answer.

**EDIT** I thought about this some more, and came up with a much more efficient algorithm:

```
% assuming column headers and data are in two separate arrays
ds1headers = {'a','bb','c'};
ds1data = [1 2 3; 2 3 4];
ds2headers = {'aa','c','d', 'e'};
ds2data = [2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7];

% as before, find unique column headers:
cols = unique({ds1headers{:} ds2headers{:}});

% convert to column numbers:
ds1conv = cellfun(@(x)find(ismember(cols, x)), ds1headers);
ds2conv = cellfun(@(x)find(ismember(cols, x)), ds2headers);

% now conversion is easy:
n1 = size(ds1data,1);
n2 = size(ds2data,1);
ds3data = zeros(n1+n2, numel(cols));

ds3data(1:n1, ds1conv) = ds1data;
ds3data(n1+(1:n2), ds2conv) = ds2data;

disp(cols)
disp(ds3data)
```

The result is

```
'a'    'aa'    'bb'    'c'    'd'    'e'

 1     0     2     3     0     0
 2     0     3     4     0     0
 0     2     0     3     4     5
 0     3     0     4     5     6
 0     4     0     5     6     7
```

Looks like it would do the trick - and no ugly loops... I recognize now that this looks a little bit like @Magla's solution below (hadn't seen it when I posted my update, but it was clearly there before my latest edit) - except I still have a cell array for column names, and a few other improvements.

Comment: Please, see the edit I made concerning cells. That's the magic of _ismember_ to work both with matrix and cells. @RoflcoptrException, could you please provide a follow up by either accepting one of the answer or giving a more detailed description of the answer you are expecting? Many thanks! (there is one guy that try to build up a reputation here ;)

Comment: @Magla - thanks for the follow up. You are right - `ismember` is a relatively new addition to my toolbox, I'm still learning just how useful it can be.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something like this. It fills the final matrix with zeros.

```
%examples (ABCD are replaced by indexes 1234)
A = [1 2 3; 11 12 13];  
B = [1 3 5 8; 111 112 113 114];  

%first mix the first rows of A and B
header = union(A(1,:), B(1,:))  

%find the corresponding indexes in A and B
[Lia,LocbA] = ismember(A(1,:),header);  
[Lia,LocbB] = ismember(B(1,:),header);  


%concatenate the second rows of A and B
C = header  
C(2,LocbA) = A(2,:);  
C(3,LocbB) = B(2,:);
```

Results:

A =

```
 1     2     3
11    12    13
```

B =

```
 1     3     5     8
111   112   113   114
```

C =

```
 1     2     3     5     8
 11    12    13    0     0
 111   0     112   113   114
```

**EDIT**: the code initially provided works with cells too (see below for an example). In this case, it fills the final cell array with empty cells. Contrary to @Floris solution, datasets to be merged are composed of both the column headers (first row) and the data (second row). I guess the data format you have will suit one of the two solutions.

```
%input modification (now with cells)
A = {'A' 'B' 'C';     11  12  13};  
B = {'A' 'C' 'E' 'H'; 111 112 113 114};
```

Results:

C =

```
'A'      'B'     'C'      'E'      'H'  
[ 11]    [12]    [ 13]    []       []
[111]    []      [112]    [113]    [114]
```

Answer (score 1):

First we create the example:

```
% Create test datasets:
A=1; 
B=2;
C=3;
save db1
A=2;
clear B;
D=4;
save db2
clear;
```

Now the script would look more or less like:

```
% Your script starts here, replace your paths with the correct paths:
path_to_db1 = 'db1';
path_to_db2 = 'db2';

db1 = load(path_to_db1);
db2 = load(path_to_db2);

merge = db1;

for field = fieldnames(db1)'
  field = field{1};
  if isfield(db2,field)
    merge.(field) = [merge.(field);db2.(field)];
  else
    merge.(field) = [merge.(field);0];
  end 
end

for field = fieldnames(db2)'
  field = field{1};
  if ~isfield(db1,field)
    merge.(field) = [0;db2.(field)];
  end
end
clear db1 db2;
```

The output:

```
>> merge.A

ans =

     1
     2

>> merge.B 

ans =

     2
     0

>> merge.C

ans =

     3
     3

>> merge.D 

ans =

     0
     4
```

But you may want them to be free variables on the workspace, not on the merge struct, so you may add the following code:

```
for field = fieldnames(merge)'
  field=field{1};
  eval(sprintf('%s = merge.%s;',field,field));
end
```